# Google Analytics Campaign: Organic keywords

Tags: google-analytics

I have been looking at the GA Help section but it isn't very clear on explaining how keywords work.

On the account I'm looking at I have found that the paid keywords and all campaigns match those used in google adwords, and natrually the refferal is Google, so I'm assuming that this is automatic since the accounts are linked.

What I don't understand is the presentation of organic keywords, they clearly come from search engines, but how does that connect to the existing adwords campaigns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Adwords**
-> you search the keywords you want. And use them as advertisement. Google puts your advert to matching content or search requests.paid keywords
**Google.de Search keywords**
 
-> google ranks your page. According to a lot of stuff, including your content and external links. Google evaluates this content and assings each of your pages several keywords regarding their content and external link texts. If another person searches in google, he will find your page under these keywords which google assesed. If he clicks this link at google, google analytics will show this keyword as organic keyword